# Function troubles

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting this error:

[image] [image]

```
var appname = angular.module('appname', []);

appname.controller("hipotecaController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.hipoteca = {
        capital: undefined,
        anyos: undefined,
        interesAplicado: "",
        interes: undefined,
        tipoEuribor: "",
        Euribor: undefined,

        interesOpcion: function () {
            return $scope.hipoteca.interesAplicado === "Fijo"
        }

        tipoOpcion: function () {
            if ($scope.hipoteca.Euribor === "EURIBOR") {
                $scope.hipoteca.Euribor = 0.8;
            }
            else if ($scope.hipoteca.Euribor === "EURIBOR3") {
                $scope.hipoteca.Euribor = 0.4;
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

I don't know what is happening. If I only use one function it does work.

Comment: Should be comma separated

Comment: I know it can be difficult but it's much better to post that error as text here instead of linking a screenshot. If the link to that image goes dead, this question will be useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a comma after the function:

```
interesOpcion:function(){
  return $scope.hipoteca.interesAplicado==="Fijo"
},       // << This comma
```

You are defining an object as `$scope.hipoteca` and after each key value (unless the last one) of the object, you have to put a comma like:

```
$scope.foo = {
    fname: "John",
    lname: "Doe",
    age: 24
};
```

Like you said, if you were defining a single function i.e. `interesOpcion` it was working, since that was the last key-value of that object so you were not getting any error. But when you defined another function i.e. `tipoOpcion`, so before defining you actually has to add a comma after function body of `interesOpcion` like above.

Answer (score 5):

You need a comma after your first function declaration as you're doing this inside an object.

```
interesOpcion:function(){
  return $scope.hipoteca.interesAplicado==="Fijo"
},
tipoOpcion:function(){
  if($scope.hipoteca.Euribor==="EURIBOR"){
    $scope.hipoteca.Euribor=0.8;
  }
  else if($scope.hipoteca.Euribor==="EURIBOR3"){
    $scope.hipoteca.Euribor=0.4;
  }
}
```

Since you don't have a trailing comma before tipOpcion, the object is expected to close, so the tipOpcion function object is an `unexpected identifier`.